# What is the difference between type of a class and superclass of a class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, class-hierarchy, object-model

I am but confused right now after writing my repeated efforts at understanding the object model of ruby : following are my observations.

```
class Bird
  def speak
   puts "tweet tweet"
  end
end

>> Bird.class
=> Class
>> Class.class
=> Class
>> Class.superclass
=> Module
>> Module.class
=> Class
>> Module.superclass
=> Object
>> Object.class
=> Class
>> Object.superclass
=> nil
>> nil.class
=> NilClass
>> NilClass.class
=> Class
>> NilClass.superclass
=> Object 
and keeps going on ....
```

What is going on here ? What lies at the apex of ancestry nil or NilClass or Object or Class ? How is Ruby's Object Model Organized.

What is a class and what is a object ? is Class a class or an object ? is Object an Object or a class ?

Comment: Might be interesting: [Ruby Inheritance](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html) -- note that 1.8 and 1.9 disagree on the tree.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9+, `Object.superclass` returns `BasicObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit tricky. In Ruby everything is an Object (depending on your version).

- Nil has its own NilClass, as it does not allow NilClass.new, which Object and Class allow. It is an object so you can call methods on it like nil.nil? etc.
- Object is the highest Class, everything inherits from Object, even NilClass
- Class is also an Object, it knows how to instantiate Objects from itself with the new method.

It is really weird at first, but I found the explanation from Dave Thomas quite revealing.

See: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/metaprogramming-ruby and http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming. The later is commercial.

Comment: BasicObject is above Object in 1.9+

Answer (score 6):

In ruby, a class object, is actually an instance of the `Class` class.  `class Foo` is nearly identical to `Foo = Class.new`

```
MyClass = Class.new
instance = MyClass.new
puts instance # => #<MyClass:0x100c14b38>
```

Also, the `class` method is more design to be called on instances, not class objects.

```
class Foo
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.class # => Foo
```

The semantics can be odd when calling on class objects.  Though `superclass` works as you would expect on a class object.

So given all that lets explain these one by one:

```
>> Bird.class
=> Class
```

`Bird` the class object has a class of `Class`, since all class objects are instances of the `Class` class.

```
>> Class.class
=> Class
```

Yep even `Class` is an instance of `Class`.  In this case it's actually a circular reference.

```
>> Class.superclass
=> Module
```

The `Class` class actually inherits from `Module`.  After all, a class is simply a module that can be instantiated.  But all non-instance functionality is pretty identical to modules.

```
>> Module.superclass
=> Object
```

`Module` inherits from `Object`.  Just like everything in ruby if you go back far enough.

```
>> Object.class
=> Class
```

Again all class objects are instances of `Class`.

```
>> Object.superclass
=> nil
```

All ruby everything starts with `Object`.  It is the base class for everything.  Therefore it has no superclass.

```
>> nil.class
=> NilClass
```

`nil` is actually an instance of `NilClass` under the hood.  `NilClass` defines methods that `nil` responds to.  You can even add methods to `NilClass` if you want.  There is also a `TrueClass` and a `FalseClass`.

```
>> NilClass.class
=> Class
```

Again all class objects are instances of `Class`.

```
>> NilClass.superclass
=> Object
```

`NilClass` inherits from `Object` like any class that does not specify an explicit superclass.

Comment: It should be pointed out that `Object.superclass => BasicObject` on 1.9+, so the results in the post and above may not agree for everyone.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't played with 1.9 much to be honest :( So please correct anything that inconsistent.  This is all however as true as I know it for 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can conclude the following from your example:

1. Every name written in uppercase that appears in your example script points to a class (`Bird`, `Class`, `Module`, `Object`, `NilClass`).
2. Every class is in turn an object of type `Class` (this is why `X.class` always returns `Class` in your example).
3. `X.superclass` returns the base class of `X`.
4. `Object.superclass` returns `nil`, because it has no base class! This does *NOT* mean that the base class of Object is `NilClass` or even `nil` (which is not a type, but an instance)
5. The inheritance diagrams of the involved classes look something like:

   ```
   Object (top-level)      Object      Object
     |                       |           |
   Module                  Bird       NilClass
     |
   Class
   ```

Comment: But in 1.9.2 ... `Object.superclass => BasicObject` and `BasicObject.superclass => nil`

Comment: That's true and this is why I wrote "You can conclude the following from your example".

Answer (score 1):

`Class` returns a class for an object (and a class is an object). Superclass is the parent class of a (derived) class.

Please, see the [Ruby Object Model](http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused about the difference between instances (like `nil`) and classes (like `NilClass`). It's reasonable to find it confusing because Ruby classes (`NilClass`) are also instances. Thus: a class is an instance. An instance is not a class though *unless* it is a class.

[Here's a detailed hierarchy](http://objectgraph.rubyforge.org/dotOG.html), which is made by [ObjectGraph](http://objectgraph.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: But in 1.9.2 ... `Object.superclass => BasicObject`